# Run mysqldump from Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, ubuntu, tomcat

I'm trying to run `mysqldump` from Spring Boot.

```
OS:           Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Bash version: 5.0.17(1)-release
Spring Boot:  2.6.7
Java:         openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19; OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+10-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1); OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.15+10-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
MySQL:        mysql  Ver 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

$ groups mysql
mysql : mysql

$ groups tomcat
tomcat : tomcat  www-data  mysql

$ ps -ef | grep mysql
mysql      54024       1  0 May06 ?        00:20:19 /usr/sbin/mysqld

$ ps -ef | grep tomcat
tomcat    122584       1  1 04:44 ?        00:04:52 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/tomcat9/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /opt/tomcat/tomcat9/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/tomcat9/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat/tomcat9 -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat/tomcat9 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/tomcat9/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  7539680 May  4 12:36 /usr/bin/mysql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  7458048 May  4 12:36 /usr/bin/mysqldump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 66334800 May  4 12:36 /usr/sbin/mysqld
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    14560 Apr 23 13:02 /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

Java code to execute `mysqldump`:

```
final String cmd = "/usr/bin/mysqldump -u username  -ppassword  --no-tablespaces  --add-drop-table --databases TheVegCat  -r /var/storage/backup/MySQL.sql";
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
}
catch (final IOException e) {
    log.warn("Database backup failure; IOException: {}", e.getMessage());
}
```

Tried to add user `tomcat` to `mysql` group and restarted Tomcat service, but nothing changed.
When I run this command from shell as a `root` user, it works.
Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: You should be reading stderr. You might then learn why it doesn't work. Better to use `ProcessBuilder` in normal circs. Whether there's anything better in Spring Boot I don't know...

Comment: (That is assuming that the `-r` parameter causes *all* stdout to be sent to that file. If it doesn't, you need to read that as well)

Comment: Runs as root because of `/var/storage/backup/MySQL.sql` permissions. Try writing to `/tmp`

Comment: @g00se it is premission thing, now I have console output:
mysqldump: Can't create/write to file '/var/storage/backup/MySQL--2022-05-08--19-25-38.sql' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
Database backup failure; external process exit code = 1

Comment: Ok, so what does `ls -ld /var/storage/backup` say?

Comment: @g00se It says "drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  8 04:47 /var/storage/backup" which is I guess not good as it can be written to only by root.

Comment: @g00se you fixed it! Now it's working. Thanks! Can you create an answer so I could mark it as solution?

Comment: I haven't given you the solution *yet* ;) What have you done?

Comment: @g00se added input stream reading console output and there I got this message from above. Then issued ```chown tomcat:tomcat /var/storage/backup/``` and it was able to write backup file. This virtual server is just for one Tomcat and one app and thus I have no problem giving backup dir exclusively to Tomcat as it's the only one who writes to it.

Comment: That's more invasive than what I suggested. Where did /var/log/backup come from - what created it?

Comment: I just did an edit of previous answer. There is only one webapp running on virtual server and this backup directory is made by me being sued as root silly me.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls -ld /var/storage/backup
```

will tell you the permissions of the directory to which you're trying to write and thus possible solutions. If it's root-only write then you *could* add user tomcat to the root group and give the directory group-write perms. but I don't like it too much. I'd prefer to write to a different directory for the sole purposes of the app.

Don't forget to consume stderr and stdout when creating a process from Java.